# saving a bitmap in android using camera intent

Tags: java, android, image, android-camera, save

I'm trying to follow this tutorial however the problem is when I click the checkmark that is supposed to confirm the image it doesn't do anything at all. I feel like I'm missing some kind of permission to access the SD card or something. I am testing on a nexus 7 in debug mode. All help appreciated thank you.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 
private static ImageView imageView;
protected String _path;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    _path =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/images/camocr";


    photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            File file = new File( _path );
            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
            intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );

            //Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            startActivityForResult( intent, 0 );
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == -1) {  
       // Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( _path, options );
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }  
} 
protected static void identifyunicode() {
    // DATA_PATH = Path to the storage
    // lang for which the language data exists, usually "eng"


}
```

}

Comment: you set the request code as 0 and in onActivityResult your checking for -1

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `requestCode` to -1 in the `onCreate` method. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

in your startActivity for result the request code is 0, and in onActivity result your checking for -1 also you have to use:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
            Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

for the picture to show up, if not it wont show up until the next time you turn the phone on